# IBM Bladecenter S: Disk Storage Module with 'non-supported' IBM SAS disk

Tags: ibm, bladecenter

We have IBM Bladecenter S with 6-Disk Storage Module (43W3581), and we need to add more disks to the system. We currently bought 4x 49Y1861 (IBM 450GB 3.5" 15K 6Gb SAS HDD), but they didn't fit the disk slot - the tray on disk was a little to thick.

Now it seems that we bought the 'wrong' disks, and should have ordered 44W2239 (IBM 450GB 3.5in SL HS 15K 6Gbps SAS HDD), which seems like basicly the same disks spec. The disks we ordered doesn't line up as supported disks on IBM whitepapers for the DSM either.

My humble question is - Is iy possible to just replace the tray on the disks and use them as-is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'possible', probably yes, on many levels they'll be very close in spec, what it won't be is supporable. Every week we get people on this site with array problem they've caused by cutting corners to save a buck, they start off with everything work but when something breaks they get no help from their vendors and come here to see if we can add some fairy dust, we can't.